# NSRegularExpression - no iPad support?

Tags: iphone, regex, ipad, nsstring

I want to use NSRegularExpression in my iPhone app, but [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says that it was first available in iOS 4. Since iPads are still running on iOS 3.2 this means that my app would not be available for iPads -- correct? Is there any way to get around this? Or do I just need to wait until apple's iOS 4.1 release which should supposedly have iPad support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/) on iPhoneOS < 3.2

Comment: I was using RegexKitLite. The main advantage I found to switching was a **huge** improvement in performance.

Comment: P.S. the solution I found was to use `NSClassFromString()` which allowed me to do different code for when the faster regex library is available.

Comment: When you say "switching was a **huge** improvement in performance", do you mean switching from RegexKitLite to NSRegularExpression was a **huge** improvement, or the other way around?

Comment: I found that going from RegexKitLite to NSRegularExpression provided a very large speed boost. Presumably, Apple has really optimized their regex support.

Answer (score 1):

NSPredicate supports regext so, depending on what you want to do, you can use NSPredicate. For example, this code tests for a valid eMail* in testString

```
NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"; 
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 
BOOL notAValidEmail = ![emailTest evaluateWithObject:testString];
```

- yes, I know it's not a perfect test but it's pretty good.